# How to Access Alternate Code for DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have Tried this code but not getting answer in WPF. How to code this in DataGrid of WPF

```
private void Change(string id, int current)
 {
 dataGridView.Rows[this.GetRowIndex(id)].Cells[8].Value = (object) current;
 }

private int GetRowIndex(string ID)
{
  int num = -1;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in (IEnumerable) this.dataGridView.Rows)
  {
    if (dataGridViewRow.Cells[0].Value.Equals((object) ID))
      num = dataGridViewRow.Index;
  }
  return num;
}
```

What is the alternative code for WPF datagridd?

Comment: Its better to change in the source..

Comment: It's not really clear from the question what you're trying to accomplish.  Rather than posting some code and asking for someone to translate it for you, describe the behavior you are trying to implement.